# How to get data from firebase using child value in flutter?

Tags: firebase, flutter, dart

I want to retrieve data from firebase via "continent" value

[here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7cdyX.png) is my database

this is my code:

```dart
DatabaseReference ref = FirebaseDatabase.instance
  .reference()
  .child("Country/")
  .orderByChild("continent")
  .equalTo("Asia");

  ref.once()
  .then((DataSnapshot datasnapshot) {
     datalist.clear();
     var keys=datasnapshot.value.keys;
     var values=datasnapshot.value;

     for(var key in keys) {
       Country data = new Country(
         values[key]['Country'],
         values[key]['continent'],
         values[key]['Capital'],
       );
     }
     datalist.add(data);
   }
```

what is wrong?

Comment: What is the error? do you get something related to index?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```dart
DatabaseReference ref = FirebaseDatabase.instance
  .reference()
  .child("Country/")
  .orderByChild("continent")
  .equalTo("Asia");

ref.once()
  .then((DataSnapshot snapshot) {
    Map<dynamic, dynamic> values = snapshot.value;
      values.forEach((key, values) {
        print(values["continent"]);
      });
  });
```

Comment: Panasheriya , thank you, but i want get just country and capital in a continent Asia , how can do that?

Comment: this answer was flagged for low quality, please better the answer with more supporting info and an explanation

Comment: @Adm i have update answer please check it.

Comment: @Jayesh Pansheriya    Thank you , it sloved

Answer (score 0):

From the 9.0.0 version of firebase_database, many breaking changes applied. Now its something like:

```
Query ref = FirebaseDatabase.instance.ref()
    .child("Country/")
    .orderByChild("continent")
    .equalTo("Asia");

ref.once()
    .then((DatabaseEvent event) {
        if(event.snapshot.value == null) return;
        var values = event.snapshot.value;
        print(values);
    });
```